# Why everyone give importance to one's own duties?

Tags: dharma, love

I heard that in Mahabharata ,not only Mahabharata in Ramayana too why do they sacrifice everything for their duties ?and why there is no importance to one's love?why everyone want to kill their beloved ones for their duties?

Comment: They didn't kill their beloved ones for their karma. They killed evil-doers for their karma.

Comment: "Everyone" is too generalised. Only few have guts to go against their own people & hence they are rare. *Swadharma* is given importance by many Yogis.

Comment: This is too broad. See How to Ask - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Give specific examples.

Comment: @sv. Just type `[ask]` in the comments and it will turn to How to Ask page. Same for answer also. You will find it helpful.